# SQL query to calculate average time duration between different events

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need help on building SQL query:

Here is my postgres table I use to store the test run statistics.

```
CREATE TABLE logs
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  test_id int,
  state text,
  start_date timestamp with time zone,
  end_date timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT logs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

This table contains test start time, end time and status.
I need to calculate i use due to a test failure. i.e time interval between a test failure and the next immediate test start.

i.e for each test failed records, get the end_date and get the start_date of the next immediate record for the same test. 
calculate the time differences. 
Sum the duration for all such failed records and devide by number of failures. to get the average.

Example :

[image]

Let's say i have following table of data, only 5 columns , last column Duration in failed state should be part of my query.

i.e i have totally 3 failed records two for test 1 and one for test 2. so `total time = 130minutes/3 = around 43.3 minutes will be in secs`.

can somebody get me the SQL query for this ?

Comment: Can you please give an example if some sample data in logs table and what would be the desired output for those records

Comment: Are you sure this is PostgreSQL? `AUTO_INCREMENT`and `DATETIME` don't look like it...

Comment: Please update your question by adding your PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Q1 - What if there is 1 pass and 2 fail rows for same test_id. Do you want the difference in end and start time in front of both the failed records? And in that case do you want total time to add that failed record twice?

Q2-If you want to take average of Pass times, why you want to populate the minutes taken to pass in front of failed record? Calculating average of 'resultant row' is easy. Putting it in front of fail is bit difficult and will very on DB you are using. 

Please confirm the same.

Comment: And what if a `test_id` starts with a fail?

Comment: Updated the table script for postgres

Comment: Utsav - Basically what i want is to know the average time duration we loose for the failed test. i.e the time between a failed record end time and the next immediate test start time. status of the next test does not matter. all i want is the time duration between end time of failed test and start time of next immediate test.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't make sense. The rows with ID=4 and 5 have an end_date that is _before_ the start_date. id=4 starts at 01:01:00 and ends at 01:00:00 (one minute before it started) and id=5 starts at 01:32 and ends at 01:04 (so it ends  28 minutes before it started). How can that be? And please do not post sample data as screenshots. It's easier for us if you post formatted text (that can be copied and pasted) or even better `insert` statements. And how are those rows sorted? Is the "next" row defined by sorting on the `ID` column? Or the `start_Date` column? Or the `end_date` column?

Comment: Yes , my bad. updated it

Comment: All you need here is to lookup the LEAD() and LAG() functions in the documentation. They allow the retrieval of a value from a different row that shares common values with the current one.

Comment: Yes , my bad. updated it `but you still used an image` = still bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned this can easily be done using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select id,  
       test_id,
       start_date, 
       end_date,
       state,
       case 
         when state = 'FAIL' then lag(start_date) over (partition by test_id order by start_date desc) - end_date
         else null
       end as time_diff
from logs
order by test_id, start_date desc;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d40f/2